# Accessing typeset in Golang from the terraform schema and iterate over the Map

Tags: go, terraform

I am trying to access a key element in Golang with the following schema via terraform config file:

```
"vehicles": {
    Type:     schema.TypeSet,
    Optional: true,
    MaxItems: 5,
    Elem: &schema.Resource{
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "car": {
                Type:     schema.TypeList,
                Optional: true,
                MaxItems: 2,
                Elem: &schema.Resource{
                    Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                        "make": {
                            Type:     schema.TypeString,
                            Optional: true,
                        },
                        "model": {
                            Type:     schema.TypeString,
                            Optional: true,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

In config file,

```
resource "type_test" "type_name" {
  vehicles {
      car {
        make = "Toyota"
        model = "Camry"
      }

      car {
        make = "Nissan"
        model = "Rogue"
      }
  }
}
```

I want to iterate over the list and access the vehicles map via Golang.

The terraform crashes with the below code:

```
vehicles_map, ok = d.getOK("vehicles")
if ok {
vehicleSet := vehicles_d.(*schema.Set)List()

for i, vehicle := range vehicleSet {
  mdi, ok = vehicle.(map[string]interface{})
  if ok {
   log.Printf("%v", mdi["vehicles"].(map[string]interface{})["car"])
 }
}
```

Crash Log:

```
2019-12-25T21 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider: panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not map[string]interface {}
```

for line `"log.Printf("%v", mdi["vehicles"].(map[string]interface{})["car"])"`

I want to print and access the each vehicles element in the config file, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then `mdi` does not have a key `"vehicles"` in it.

Comment: @icza yes you are right, when I print I get the following:                                 map[car:[map[model:Toyota make:Camry] map[model:Nissan make:Rogue]]],         Do you have any idea on how to iterate and print each of the inner elements ?

Answer (score 4):

`d.getOK("vehicles")` already performs the indexing with `"vehicles"` key, which results in a [`*schema.Set`](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/helper/schema#Set). Calling its [`Set.List()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/helper/schema#Set.List) method, you get a slice (of type `[]interface{}`). Iterating over its elements will give you values that represent a `car`, modeled with type `map[string]interface{}`. So inside the loop you just have to type assert to this type, and not index again with `"vehicles"` nor with `"car"`.

Something like this:

```
for i, vehicle := range vehicleSet {
    car, ok := vehicle.(map[string]interface{})
    if ok {
        log.Printf("model: %v, make: %v\n", car["model"], car["make"])
    }
}
```

Comment: @KaranKotabagi Can you post your exact output?

Comment: I was trying to print a single value like as of car["model"] in the inner for loop, just get the output as "<nil>" in the terminal for this particular logging.

Comment: @KaranKotabagi Can you print it like: `fmt.Printf("%T %v", vehicle, vehicle)`